# is it possible to have a relationship between entity attributes?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

Lets say we have 2 entities. `Driver` and `car`. The `Driver` has a `licence type` (`manual or automatic`) attribute.

And the `car` entity has a attribute `transmission` specifying (`manual` `or` `automatic` transmission type).

In order for the driver to drive a automatic car, they must have a automatic licence and vice versa for manual.

Can this constraint be modeled in a EER diagram?

If not, how can this constraint be possibly represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CarDriver{Reg*,LicenceID*,Transmission*}
|  |
|  +---(LicenceID,Transmission)----Driver{LicenceID*,Transmission*}
|
+---(Reg,Transmission)----Car{Reg*,Transmission}
```

(* = primary key. For clarity I have used Transmission instead of "licence type")

The constraint referencing the Car entity is called an *inclusion dependency* - loosely, a "foreign key" where the target of the constraint is not necessarily a candidate key, i.e. (Reg,Transmission).